# Replacing String Values With Mean Of the Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset with 200+ columns. I need to do preprocessing on it and the most of the numerical attributes have random string values in them, 'XX'.

I want to get rid of all the 'XX' in the dataset and replace them with the mean of each corresponding column.

I understand how I would do it for each individual column using .replace and np.mean , but I havent been able to figure out how to apply it to all the columns.

aka I understand:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace('XX', 
    np.mean(pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce')))
```

but need a generalized version of it that I can apply to all columns that have string values in them

Answer (score 1):

Some test data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

testdata = {'A': ['XX', 0.09, 0.76, 'XX', 0.65, 0.21, 0.18, 0.97, 'XX', 'XX'],
            'B': ['XX', 0.46, 0.29, 'XX', 0.44, 0.59, 'XX', 0.47, 0.37, 'XX']}

df = pd.DataFrame(testdata)

>>> df.head()
      A     B
0    XX    XX
1  0.09  0.46
2  0.76  0.29
3    XX    XX
4  0.65  0.44
```

Then you can do:

```py
>>> df = df.replace("XX", np.nan)
>>> df.head()
      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1  0.09  0.46
2  0.76  0.29
3   NaN   NaN
4  0.65  0.44

>>> df.fillna(df.mean()).head()
          A         B
0  0.476667  0.436667
1  0.090000  0.460000
2  0.760000  0.290000
3  0.476667  0.436667
4  0.650000  0.440000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two steps!

1. fill the string values with NaN values
   (if dtype of the column if 'object' do `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int/float)`)
2. then fillna with mean